# Is there any function in SKlearn to solve a large linear regression with l2 norm efficient?

Tags: scikit-learn, linear-regression

Now, I need to solve a very large linear regression with L2 norm(y=xw, y.shape=[5,1],x.shape=[5,100K+]).
I have tried `sklearn.linear_model.Ridge`, but it too slow(cost more than 30min)
SO, is `SKlearn` have another function to solve a large linear regression efficentilly?

Comment: i don't think your regression makes any sense at all. you have 5 observations and 100K+ variables to regress?

Comment: I think so, but 'Face Alignment at 3000 FPS via Regressing Local Binary Features' solve a large linear-regression with [y=68*2 x=100k+] in section 3.2, and predicets face alignment succesfully. i guess the sparsity of X contributes to this process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a different solver, e.g. an iterative one and set `max_iter` lower or `tol` higher. From the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html):

> - ‘sparse_cg’ uses the conjugate gradient solver as found in scipy.sparse.linalg.cg. As an iterative algorithm, this solver is more
>   appropriate than ‘cholesky’ for large-scale data (possibility to set
>   tol and max_iter).
> - ‘lsqr’ uses the dedicated regularized least-squares routine scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr. It is the fastest and uses an iterative
>   procedure.
> - ‘sag’ uses a Stochastic Average Gradient descent, and ‘saga’ uses its improved, unbiased version named SAGA. Both methods also use an
>   iterative procedure, and are often faster than other solvers when both
>   n_samples and n_features are large. Note that ‘sag’ and ‘saga’ fast
>   convergence is only guaranteed on features with approximately the same
>   scale. You can preprocess the data with a scaler from
>   sklearn.preprocessing.

Comment: Thank you very much! In addition, I forget to mention that: x is a very sparse binary matrix. I belive a sparse solver may improve the spead.

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to upvote and accept my answer if it solved your problem ;)